# NG-Repeat with NG-show Not executing with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to get a client list and detail view to work but i cant seem to figure it out.  The NG-init wont work nor will the ng-click, I can get it to work if its hard coded, but when dynamically loading data it wont work.  Id appreciate if anyone can point out the correct way to execute this.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="ClientCtrl as clients">
    <table class="listview">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="stuff in clients.records">
                <td><a ng-click="client = {{$index}}"  class="client-link">{{stuff.first_name}} {{stuff.last_name}}</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="detailview">
        <div ng-repeat-start="things in clients.records " ng-if="$first">
            <div id="contact-{{$index}}" class="tab-pane active"  ng-show="client == {{$index}}" ng-init="client = {{$index}}">
                <h2>{{things.first_name}} {{things.last_name}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat-end="things in clients.records " ng-if="!$first">
            <div id="contact-{{$index}}" class="tab-pane active"  ng-show="client == {{$index}}" ng-init="client = {{$index}}">
                <h2>{{things.first_name}} {{things.last_name}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.js:

```
function ClientCtrl($scope,$http,$interval, $rootScope){
    var ClientCtrlData = this;
    $http.get("api/clients").success(function(response) {
        ClientCtrlData.records = response.records;
    });
    var promise;
    // simulated items array
    $scope.items = [];
    // starts the interval
    $scope.start = function() {
        // stops any running interval to avoid two intervals running at the same time
        $scope.stop();
        // store the interval promise
        promise =   $interval(
            function(){
                $http.get("api/clients").success(function(response) {
                    ClientCtrlData.records = response.records;
                    console.log("People loaded");
                });
            }.bind(this)
            ,1000000 * 10);
    };
    // stops the interval
    $scope.stop = function() {
        $interval.cancel(promise);
    };
    // starting the interval by default
    $scope.start();
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        $scope.stop();
    });
}


angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .controller('ClientCtrl',ClientCtrl)
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/yzN787uL6C82Z6g6JNOq

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you share a plnkr/fiddle?

Comment: Try changing ClientCtrlData.records = response.records to $scope.records = response.records

Comment: also, when you declare your module, you have to declare the dependencies as-well, so when you declare the first time you need to say `angular.module('inspinia',[])` rather than `angular.module('inspinia')`

Comment: ClientCtrlData.records is there for initial data load, wouldnt changing it to $scope.records stop that?

Comment: @RocoCTZ the dependencies are declared in anther part of the app, this is just an individual piece

Comment: still, it would be great if you shared a plnkr with some standalone code, much easier to find out what the problem is

Comment: @RocoCTZ working on that at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, no need to use `ng-click="client = {{$index}}"`, you're already saying that the code should be parsed by angular so no need for the angular brackets `{{ }}`.

Second, you need to scope client inside `ng-click="client = $index"` for example as such `ng-click="clients.client = $index"`, otherwise angular doesn't know where to look for the property.

I also wonder what the need for the `ng-init` is? I'm guessing this is just mock functionality, because now it will just set the `clients.client` variable for each item until it ends up being the last one in the list.

In any case, here's a version of your code with fixed syntax, you should be able to take it from here

http://plnkr.co/edit/UyKYvxpErcehizSBKaqy?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="ClientCtrl as clients">
  <table class="listview">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="stuff in clients.records">
        <td>
          <a ng-click="clients.client =  $index" class="client-link">{{stuff.first_name}} {{stuff.last_name}}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="detailview">
    <div ng-repeat="things in clients.records ">
      <div id="contact-{{$index}}" class="tab-pane active" ng-show="clients.client == $index" ng-init="clients.client = $index">
        <h2>{{things.first_name}} {{things.last_name}}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```